# Tableau highlight few bars in chart

Tags: tableau-api

I have a tableau chart with categories (A-meaning of A, B-meaning of B etc) and the corresponding values of each category.

Please find image as attached - I want to highlight the 3 rows starting with 'E' for this time because each capital letter should only have 1 meaning.

This might change because the data gets once a week - I might need to highlight other category next time with the duplicated leading letter.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following: 
1) Create a calculated field that returns the first letter of each the field:

```
left([Field],1)
```

2) Create a calculated field to flag letters duplicated leading letters. I have used a fixed level of detail calculation so that the calculation is not affected by the composition of the view or filters:

```
{ FIXED [First Field]: COUNTD([Field]) } > 1
```

This will create a field where leading letters that occur more than one meaning will be flagged as True